# how to for every parent node select every not first child node in a tree with multiple parent nodes

Tags: xpath, xslt

His,

I think I've got a tricky questions for XPath experts. There is a node structure like this:

```
A(1)-|
     |-B(1)
     |-B(2)
     |-B(3)
A(2)-|
     |-B(2.1)
     |-B(2.2)
     |-B(2.3)
...
```

How to, with a single XPath-expression, extract only the following nodes

```
A(1)-|
     |-B(2)
     |-B(3)
A(2)-|
     |-B(2.2)
     |-B(2.3)
...
```

That is for every parent node its first child element should be excluded.

I tried A/B[position() != 1] but this would filter out only B(1.1) and select B(2.1).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricky. You could select nodes that have preceding siblings:

```
A/B[preceding-sibling::*]
```

This will fail for the first element and succeed for the rest.

Comment: You beat me to it by five seconds.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it out too. Somehow it doesn't work on xalan i am using. 

Actually, according to results i've got at http://www.futurelab.ch/xmlkurs/xpath.en.html, the solution with position() != 1 should work as well, but it doesn't on my system. 

Are there any particularities that one should keep in mind using xalan (2.7.1)?

Comment: Thanks. That was my mistake. Both solutions work (preceding-sibling::* and position()=1]

Answer (score 4):

**This XPath expression** (no `preceding-sibling::` axis used):

```
/*/a/*[not(position()=1)]
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
 <a>
   <b11/>
   <b12/>
   <b13/>
 </a>
 <a>
   <b21/>
   <b22/>
   <b23/>
 </a>
</t>
```

**selects the wanted nodes**:

```
<b12 />
<b13 />
<b22 />
<b23 />
```

**This can be verified with this XSLT transformation, producing the above result**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/*/a/*[not(position()=1)]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. That was my mistake. Both solutions work (preceding-sibling::* and position()=1]